# Can't get SD card back to full capacity

Tags: partitioning, storage, sd-card

64GB micro sd card was being used for Raspian on a pi 3 b. now I wan't to use it for retropie.

tried formatting it from the stock OS formatter and it wont go above I believe 62MB. checked partitions via easus & Partition Wizard and made sure I deleted & wiped the partition. it says it should be 64GB but it still is not.

Thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean 62MB or 62GB?

Comment: @KennethL I mean 62MB. It's stock full capacity is 64GB but now for some reason wont go beyond 62MB

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but changing drive letter from 'D' to 'Y' fixed the problem. Brought it back to 64GB and also made it visible in Windows again. Then when I changed back from 'Y' to 'D' it seemed like everything was still okay. Any idea why this could be? Why did simply changing from D to Y and back to D resolve the problem? Thank you!